# Illustrator ruler pixelated and white canvas background

Tags: adobe-illustrator

So my screen background is white and the ruler is pixelated, but only for this one document. It also doesn't do it for other people in my team?

What could be the causes for these artifacts I am seeing?

[image]

Comment: AI is notorious for lagging/acting strange with large files - looking at your list of artboards, I'm assuming its a large file. InDesign handles these files better for multiple reasons.

Comment: Hello Jono, welcome to GDSE. We adhere to a strict Q&A format. So please refrain from asking more than one question at a time, because that will lead to confusing multiple-answers-in-one-answer. I took the liberty of editing your question to adhere to our standards. Also, we are a design community, not tech support. It looks like you are trying to solve a _software_ problem, not a _design_ problem.

Comment: Screen draw issues... If repeatable by *everyone*.. it's an app issue (bug). If *only* visible on your system.. it's a hardware issue.. not enough (or bad) RAM, poor video card, full hard drive, etc. Either way it's tech support, contact Adobe.

Comment: Even while I type right now there's a message asking me to be nice, I feel like a couple of the above comments are being overly harsh to someone trying to resolve an illustrator problem that's more than likely a setting.

Comment: @JamiePatt I'm sorry you feel a couple comments are "harsh". I, personally, don't see that. Users here *know* that this issue is most likely *not* some "setting". Rather an issue with the hardware or how the software relates to the users Operating System. It's not "harsh" to inform the user that we can't help with that here. In fact, that's helpful in itself. This question will most likely never be answered here due to its tech support nature. I assure you there is no Illustrator "setting" that will address the issue in the question - especially if it is only a problem on *one* computer.